# How to prove the open interval $(1,5)$ is a convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis

I want to prove the interval $(1,5)$ is a convex set.

A convex set is a set having all the convex linear combinations of its point in it, where a convex linear combination is a linear combination of the form $X=(1-\alpha)X_1+ \alpha X_2$ where $\alpha$ lies between $0$ and $1$ and the sum of coefficients of above linear combination is equal to 1.

How can we prove the interval $(1,5)$ a convex set?

Comment: Take any two $x_1, x_2$ from the interval and any $\alpha\in[0,1]$. Prove that $\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2$ is in the interval.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to prove that for every $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and every pair $x_1$, $x_2$ $\in (1,5)$, $\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2$ also lies in $(1,5)$.

Suppose without loss of generality that $x_1 \leq x_2$. Then for every $\alpha \in (0,1)$ (which implies that both $\alpha$ and $1-\alpha$ are positive)

$\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2 \leq \alpha x_2 + (1-\alpha)x_2 = x_2$

and

$\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2 \geq \alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_1 = x_1$.

Hence we find that for every $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2 \in [x_1,x_2]$.

Hence for every pair $x_1$, $x_2$, any convex-combination of $x_1$, $x_2$ lies in $[x_1,x_2]$. And since $x_1$, $x_2$ $\in (1,5)$, every convex-combination of any two points in $(1,5)$ also lies in $(1,5)$.

Comment: an exrcise is given in a book that prove X=(-1/2,1/2,7/4) is the convex linear combination of X1,X2 and X3??? we did'nt provided with that X1,X2 and X3...either this question  is wrong or there  any way to prove it??

Answer (score 2):

If $x_1\leq x_2$ then $$x=(1-\alpha)x_1+\alpha x_2=x_1+\alpha(x_2-x_1)$$ If $\alpha \in [0,1]$ then $$0\leq \alpha(x_2-x_1)\leq x_2-x_1$$ so: $$x_1\leq x\leq x_1+(x_2-x_1)=x_2$$
Then $x_1,x_2\in (1,5)$ gives: $$1< x_1\leq x\leq x_2<5$$

Comment: why we are taking x1<x2 here??when x2>x1 then alpha will be less then zero...which is against covexity condition that is alpha should lie between 0 and 1....is this rzn for taking x1<x2???

Comment: we do not take $x_1<x_2$ but $x_1\leq x_2$. If both are elements of $\mathbb R$ then you will have $x_1\leq x_2$ *or* $x_2\leq x_1$. You could say that the answer deals with case $x_1\leq x_2$ and it is quite obvious that the same way of proving can be handled in the other case. Just switch the roles of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: an exrcise is given in a book that prove X=(-1/2,1/2,7/4) is the convex linear combination of X1,X2 and X3??? we did'nt provided with that X1,X2 and X3...either this question is wrong or there any way to prove it??

Comment: It is not be the right way to go deeper into this in a comment on this answer. I advice you to post your problem as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

- $1<X_1<5\Rightarrow 1-\alpha<(1-\alpha)X_1<5(1-\alpha)$
- $1<X_1<5\Rightarrow \alpha<\alpha X_2<5\alpha$

Can you now bound $(1-\alpha)X_1+ \alpha X_2$ just by adding above two inequalities?